# TextBox Text not Wrapping

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I have a `TextBox` in `WPF` that I want to wrap text when it is too long to fit in the width of the `TextBox`. I define it like this;

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="7"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="5" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
AcceptsReturn="True" MinHeight="222" MaxHeight="222" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

This is held within a `Column` in a `DataGrid`, that looks like this;

```
<ColumnDefinition MinWidth="400" MaxWidth="400"/>
```

To me this should mean that the text does not exceed the width of the `Column`, i.e. 400. However, when text is inputted into the `TextBox` it just continues in one long line instead of wrapping. How can I prevent this and implement wrapping?

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
              <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="270" MaxWidth="270"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
              <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="130" MaxWidth="130"/>
              <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="400" MaxWidth="400"/>
              <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="210" MaxWidth="210"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition/>
              <RowDefinition MinHeight="33"/>
              <RowDefinition MinHeight="33"/>
              <RowDefinition MinHeight="33"/>
              <RowDefinition MinHeight="33"/>
              <RowDefinition/>
              <RowDefinition/>
              <RowDefinition/>
              <RowDefinition/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I have created a test project and tried your example. Everything works fine. Could you provide full XAML?

Comment: @Roma I've updated with the parents of the `TextBox`, it resides within here. Does that help? - EDIT: Just looking at this I've noticed the problem, its the `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` on the `ScrollViewer`

Comment: Yes, now I can reproduce it.

Comment: I had a problem like this not long ago, fixed by putting my `TextBlock` in a `ViewBox`. Don't know whether it works with `TextBox`, but worth a try.